# Instances of class polynomial

Tags: python

How can I get coefficients to list from three different ways of creating new instances of class Polynomial?

```
class Polynomial(object)
    def __init__(self,*args)
        self.coeffs=[]
        ... 

pol1 = Polynomial([1,-3,0,2])
pol2 = Polynomial(1,-3,0,2)
pol3 = Polynomial(x0=1,x3=2­,x1=-3)
```

I am expecting for example: `pol2 = Polynomial(1,-3,0,2)`, output is `2x^3-3x+1`. But I need to get coefficients to list to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that one of the three ways is always used, you can do the following (without any validation):

```
class Polynomial(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args and isinstance(args[0], list):  # Polynomial([1,-3,0,2])
            self.coeffs=args[0]
        elif args:  # Polynomial(1,-3,0,2)
            self.coeffs=args
        else:  # Polynomial(x0=1,x3=2­,x1=-3)
            self.coeffs=[kwargs.get(x, 0) for x in ('x0', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3')]

    def __str__(self):
        s = ''
        for i, x in reversed(list(enumerate(self.coeffs))):
             if x:
                  if x > 0:
                      s += '+'
                  s += str(x)
                  if i > 0:
                      s += 'x'
                  if i > 1:
                      s += '^' + str(i)
        return '0' if not s else s.lstrip('+')


pol1 = Polynomial([1,-3,0,2])
pol2 = Polynomial(1,-3,0,2)
pol3 = Polynomial(x0=1, x1=-3, x3=2)

print(pol1)  # 2x^3-3x+1
print(pol2)  # 2x^3-3x+1
print(pol3)  # 2x^3-3x+1
```

Comment: thx a lot, and do you think there is any possible way do this for variable count of coefficients?

Comment: There always is :) But with the generic `init` that also accepts kwargs, it will be difficult to have completely arbitrary degrees of polynomials. But this at least covers lower degrees for e.g. `x3=0`

Comment: @george Actually, if you use one of the first two ways of initialising, this already covers arbitrary numbers of coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to schwobaseggl's response, I'd add this kind of checking:

```
if type(args[0]) == list:
    self.coeffs=args

# ...
else:
    self.coeffs=[kwargs.get(x, 0) for x in ['x'+i for i in range(len(kwargs))]]
```

Comment: hmm.. `args` is always of type `tuple`. And the other check might fail because, as in the OP's example `x2` is omitted as 0, there might be some `xi` missing inbetween so that the number of kwargs is not necessarily the highest `xi`